# How do I calculate the geocoordinates along a circle of fixed radius around a fixed geocoodinate?

Tags: c#, math, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to write a c# class to do the following.
In my image, I have a central geocoordinate on earth and I want to be able to get the geocoordinates that fall around that point at a fixed distance away.

I know three things

1 - central geocoordinate

2 - the distance away from the central point (either in Kilometers or in degrees latitude)

3 - and one geocoordinate along the circle

How can I get any other point along the circle?

Note:  the center is NOT located on the earths geographic pole, but can be anywhere on earth

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that your circle is positioned in the center of .net graphics coordinate system you can use cos and sin functions inside Math class:

[image]

If "a" is an known angle and "r" is circle radius you can use following formula:

```
        double x = r * Math.Cos(a);
        double y = r * Math.Sin(a);
```

In the end you just need to add coordinates "cx" (circle center x), "cy" (circle center y) where your circle is positioned:

```
double xAbsolute = cx + x;
double yAbsolute = cy + y;
```

Happy coding!

Comment: But my radius isn't a straight line, its curved along the surface of the earth

Comment: This does not make any sense to me. If you know the center of your circle and its radius (as you have wrote in description) then you just need to set specific angle and you can calculate point on circle.